# connection_aborted not working in php, apache2

Tags: php, session, authentication, header, logout

So I am creating a user login, logout system. Whenever the user wants to login, it creates a row in a Sessions table. Then if the user wants to logout, it sets an integer to one in that session. But, if the user closes the browser I cannot detect that. I am using **connection_aborted** to do that, however it is not working.
I set the **output_buffering** to Off in the php.ini, but I do not know what is happening!

```
if (connection_aborted()) {
        mkdir("connection_aborted", 0777);
    }
```

Comment: Closing a browser does not mean connection aborted necessarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connection_aborted()` just checks whether the client/server connection (typically the tcp/ip connection) has been aborted, not whether the browser window has been closed.

To detect ending the session you need a solution in javascript like the one presented e.g. in the the blog post [jQuery & Javascript – Capture the Browser or Tab Closed Event](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/)